# Set prettier blank lines after import?

Tags: javascript, prettier

I like to keep my imports like this:

```
import { ValidationError } from "../errors/validation.error";
// Blank
// Blank
function doSomething() {


}
```

With two blank lines after the imports. Prettier formats the JS with only one blank line after the imports. How do I set it to as much blank lines as I want?

Comment: I am currently investigating this myself as I like 3 lines. Will report back if I find a solution.

Comment: This is the closest thing I've found https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/554#issuecomment-351517698 The people behind Prettier don't care to add the option.

Comment: I spent some time to create my own eslint-config https://www.npmjs.com/package/@inc/eslint-config and simply added a format script that runs "eslint --fix". Works for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you happen to be using ESLint in conjunction with Prettier...

1. `yarn add eslint-plugin-import --dev`   [here](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import)
2. Add this to your `.eslintrc.js`
   `import/newline-after-import": ["error", { "count": 2 }]`  [here](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/newline-after-import.md)
3. Profit

If you happen to be using the eslint settings for [AirBnB Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) then just do #2 and you're done!